# Blow/Puff/Piston sound made by laptop "LG Gram 14" after Windows update

Tags: windows-10, laptop

**Context**:

I have a new laptop, labelled LG Gram 14 14Z90N. I bought it a few weeks ago and it's fantastic. Yesterday (end of September 2021) I got a Windows 10 update.

**Problem**:

Speakers don't work anymore, they only emit intermittent audio with a lot of white noise when I play a song.

But if I insert a headphone it does work perfect (the headphone).

When playing nothing, **and even having the windows audio setting as mute**, it emits a short sound each 8-10 seconds that can be described visually as:

> Pfff!...

The sound does not last long, less than 1 second each time.

More words to describe the sound are:

- An unusually strong air blow
- A puff sound
- Someone blowing out of the computer
- A piston at work

It is really annoying, especially due to the fact that I work in a silent environment and the sound can disturb other people in the area.

**Notes**:

- The laptop did not suffer any accident, other than a Windows update.
- The laptop is not getting warm in any place on the surface.
- This happens always, even with CPU usage at 5%.

**The question is**: what can I do to "debug" this issue?

**UPDATE**:

Disabling the speaker device itself did not fix the problem, but **disabling the audio controller** did in fact fix it.

[image]

I looked for driver updates but there aren't any. Also I tried to roll back the driver update but it is not possible.

What do you suggest? Should I keep it disabled until there is an update?

The list of updated drivers in this Win update is:

[image]

Comment: Failing HDD can be ruled out, the laptop uses M.2 SSD.

Comment: try changing the device driver to the generic Microsoft HD audio driver: update driver > browse local computer > let me pick > Microsoft "High Definition Audio Device". I think the device listed in your screenshots is Conexant chipset and I recall whispers of problematic drivers/lack of updates recently and the generic driver was mentioned as a possible solution. Their older driver may have even been a cause for MS to block a win-10 version upgrade, and using the generic one got around the issue

Comment: @Yorik I did the change and restarted the laptop but it keeps doing the same noise. At least now I know it's a drivers issue. Thanks for your good intention, appreciate it as much as if it had worked!